# Attendee List with confirmation delete button

Tags: php, jquery

I have an attendee list with records of whom have filled out the event form. Each table row has a delete button attached so that the administrator can delete a record from the database. I have tried to attach a confirmation dialog (yes/no) to the form when a delete button is clicked.

Before i attached the javascript it was deleteing a record fine, but now although the dialog box appears and works it is not deleting the record. Here is my code:

```
<form id="attending" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
    <table class="attendees">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="name">Name</th>
                <th class="company">Company</th>
                <th class="email">Email</th>
                <th class="contact">Contact</th>
                <th class="day">Day</th>
                <th class="time">Time</th>
                <th class="delete">&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
            <tr>
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
                <td class="name"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
                <td class="company"><?php echo $row['company']; ?></td>
                <td class="email"><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>
                <td class="contact"><?php echo $row['contact']; ?></td>
                <td class="day"><?php echo $row['day']; ?></td>
                <td class="time"><?php echo $row['event-time']; ?></td>
                <td class="delete"><input type="submit" name="delete" class="delete-button" value="Delete"> </td>
            </tr>

    <?php if(isset($_POST['delete'])) { 
       $id = $_POST['id'];
       mysql_query("DELETE FROM `registered_blue` WHERE `id` = '$id' ");
       }
    ?>
  <?php } ?>
    </table>
</form>
```

Here is my jquery that follows:

```
var confirmDelete = $('<div></div>')
        .html('Record will be deleted! This operation can\'t be undone. <br />Are you sure?')
        .dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            title: 'Attendee will be deleted! Please Confirm.',
            buttons: {"Yes": function() { 
                $(this).dialog("close"); 
                $('#attending').submit();
            }, "No": function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
         }
         }
    });  
    $('.delete-button').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(confirmDelete).dialog('open');
    });
```

Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong? Thanks

Comment: Is it submiting the form correctly?

Comment: Now I've added the javascript I don't think it is submitting, or it is but not deleteing the record from the database.

Comment: You're reusing the same `name` attributes on your form elements within your loop. Only the last row values will be posted

Comment: I think <?php if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {  is a problem, it is not setting delete value because you are submiting form using javascript and not on the actual click

Comment: How would i name each delete button?

Comment: Ah yes K D. How would i get around this?

Answer (score 0):

The following script will pop up a JavaScript dialog when clicking on anything with a "delete-button" class. If the user clicks on 'yes', the app will proceed with the default thing to do, and if the user clicks on 'no', the app will stop whatever it's supposed to do.

```
$('.delete-button').click(function () {
    return window.confirm("Attendee will be deleted! Please Confirm.');
});
```

You can do this with your original script too, the only thing you need is to return true if you want it to proceed with the default thing, and return false if you want it to stop.

EDIT: I think this should do it:

```
$('.delete-button').on('click', function(e){
    $('<div></div>')
    .html('Record will be deleted! This operation can\'t be undone. <br />Are you sure?')
    .dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        title: 'Attendee will be deleted! Please Confirm.',
        buttons: {"Yes": function() { 
            var result = true;
            $(this).dialog("close"); 
        }, "No": function() {
            var result = false;
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
    return result;
});
```

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit lost, could you please amend my script with this method?

Comment: A few problems with this, it dosn't delete the record on first click, the dialog box does not open and it only deletes last record no matter which delete button is pressed.

Comment: I think there are more issues than i thought with his, back to the drawing board :(

Comment: You should use links with the ID instead of buttons, because the last input with the name "id" will be used, the others ignored in this case. So just use a link for this. As for the script, I edited it again, I hope it will work now.

Comment: When you say links, so replace the inputs with anchor tags with an ID on each?

Comment: The edited script didnt really change anything sorry, the dialog box does still not open.